How will future NOTAM exchange world wide work with DigitalNOTAM?
As by my knowledge the world wide exchange of NOTAMs is based on the ICAO format within the AFTN - between all the ANSP, including as biggest the FAA(USA) and Eurocontrol(Europe).   This is as well by their own safety regulations.
Even the FAA provides the international important NOTAM in the standard ICAO format.
How should this work once the DigitalNOTAM (Based on the AIXM 5.1 Event Extension) is fully introduced?

The DigitalNOTAM is not 100% standardized and even Eurocontrol & the FAA do use different versions/dialects of the AIXM 5.1 and the Event Extensions.
How can compatibility be guaranteed between all the parties in the world wide Aeronautical community?

As by my understanding the AFTN network will not work with the XML based format (as the addresses are provided there not like used for the AFTN messages) - or would everybody just adapt their network clients (switches/router/message handling applications)?
I do not see there any action in that direction.

Is the idea that the ANSPs provide their data only via the SWIM interfaces?
I also see, that the SWIM "standard" is not used in the same way by all parties in the the Aeronautical community - like for AIXM.

For the FAA - Maybe not 100% related?
4.1: Is the FAA providing as well the Domestic/FDC NOTAM via AFTN or convert them to ICAO format for AFTN?
4.2: Would/or does the FAA provide the Domestic/FDC NOTAM as converted digitalNOTAM?

I do understand that both regulators EASA/FAA do say that for safety reasons the ANSPs do have to use the new DigitalNOTAM format (AIXM 5.1 Event Extension) - but do they provide more details - considering that without more details and the incompatibility between the different dialects, this will limit the safety improvements wanted.



It is difficult to speak about future. Note: having different dialects it is often not a problem (as long they are well defined): if you operate in different regulation areas you just assure your (airline) software is compatible with such areas. -- And I think you ask too many questions (which it is not good for this site format and so this site rules). Ask a generic (not too generic question), and then follow up questions. It may take more time to get all answered (I do not think), but nobody of us should invest so much time to write a book (comprehensive answer), so people may not answer

What does prevent digital Notams generated using AIXM schedules to be sent using the path of manual Notams, with or without an automated interface?
